# Is any Tomcat setup needed for two way SSL using Apache?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat, ssl

I have an application which runs on tomcat and hosts certain webservices. I also have an separate Apache server which has the configuration for one way and two way SSL setup. It has Virtualhost listening on 8881 which eventually redirect calls to tomcat port 8080 via AJP. I have also configured a **cacerts.crt** in Apache which contains all trusted CA certs which my clients use.

Do I need to configure similar truststore or trusted CA in tomcat as well for SSL to work successfully?

Or SSL is completely handled by apache and tomcat can be free from any such setting. In which case would tomcat need to be aware of allowed clients?

Comment: Did you try searching for [`tomcat ajp client certificate`](https://www.google.com/#q=tomcat+ajp+client+certificate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that no client cert setup is needed in tomcat as I am using apache to do that. All the cert setup is needed in apache side, Apache will do the ssl handling and if client is authenticated, the request will be redirected to tomcat via ajp port.